# MySQL Binary Logging Format - Disk Filling Up

Tags: mysql, binary-log

I have a MySQL server instance configured with binary logging enabled. I don't do any replication, but the binary logs are part of our recovery plan - to be able to replay all the transactions since the last full backup.

Not too long ago, it was noticed on a system that had been running for a few weeks that the MySQL error log had grown to the unruly size of over 5 GB. Looking into the log, almost every line written to it was a warning about an "Unsafe statement written to the binary log".

Now, I do not control the application that is using the database, so I am unable to try and make these statements "safe". So, as a "fix", I configured the **binlog_format** to **MIXED**, rather than **STATEMENT**. This tells MySQL to use **STATEMENT** logging where possible, but fall back to **ROW** logging with unsafe statements. Doing this has successfully kept the size of the error log to a manageable size.

HOWEVER, now the binary logs are growing *much* faster than they used to (I saw **3 GB** of log files in just a few hours today), presumably because now the system is writing to the log for every row that is affected (for "unsafe" statements), and for statements that affect a large number of rows, well, you get the picture.

So, I find myself between a rock and a hard place. If I use the **STATEMENT** format, the binary logs are manageable, but I get an insane number of warnings in the error log. If I use the **MIXED** format, the error log is fine, but the binary logs grow fast enough to possibly fill the partition in even a single day.

Which brings me to my quesion: what exactly is the repercussion of these "unsafe" statements? Like I said, I don't have any replication going on, so I don't need to worry about one server being exactly the same as another. I simply need to ensure that in the case that we need to restore from a backup, all of the data is there. Will the logging of "unsafe" statements cause data loss, or will there just be a situation where certain rows are in different orders (and possibly with different primary key id's)? If it's not a huge deal, then I can disable warnings in the error log (though that does seem heavy-handed).

Otherwise, I may be forced to do away with the binary logging altogether and just rely on potentially out-of-date full backups for the recovery plan.

Any advice in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row based replication format actually uses more disk space than statement based. That is simple because into the binlog you would have all data that was inserted/updated not just the statement. So if a statement says to insert 100 rows if binlog_format=STATEMENT will insert just one statement but if is ROW will actually contain all entries.

So in order to save disk space you have to revert to STATEMENT based. Into a mix mode mysql will try to write as a STATEMENT into the binlog but in case of a unsafe statements will revert to ROW based. In your case it looks like you have many unsafe statements so you end up with ROW based binlogs.

You can do a few things

- leave it as ROW and implement a clean up job that will purge the logs after a period of time, this you need to calculate what is appropriate for your system. Before you delete the logs you should copy them somewhere else so you don't loose it.
- implement replication via a second system and again have a clean up job on master (make sure the slave is in sync or you may loose data)
- have a good look at the statements that are potential unsafe, this may require collaboration with the developers of your application.

Comment: Thanks for input. Sounds like the best option for me is to try to periodically clean them up. Fortunately, I've found that I can (usually) compress a 1-gig binary log file down to about 70 megs, so I'm not overly concerned about running out of space on my backup machine.